# how can i align icons in my mid page? fcc product landing page

Tags: html, css

I was working on the Product Landing Page project of FCC, i'm having a problem with alignin the icons in the mid page. This is the code https://jsfiddle.net/mvrxw/wn7t1fr2/1/

```css
#sell {
  text-align: justify;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: left;
}

.hero {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 6%;
}

.elemnt {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  text-align: left;
}

i {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="sell">
  <div class="hero features">
    <i class="fa fa-gear" style="font-size:70px;"></i>
    <div class="elemnt">
      <h3>Only from renewable resource</h3>
      <p>We don't like to leave back footprints... shhh!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hero purchase">
    <i class="fa fa-dollar" style="font-size: 70px;"></i>
    <div class="elemnt">
      <h3>Renewable resource means lower prices!</h3>
      <p>Look at the options below, you might be curious ;)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried everything using flex and margins but I dont want to find myself using pixels to align them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use left and right margins to force your `.hero` divs into center of display with a width of 50% of the display.  This should align your icons with the text you have now and an average sized desktop display, but if your text is much shorter and/or your display is much larger (such that the text and the icon together don't take up 50% of the display) you will have to choose between having your content perfectly centered or perfectly aligned.  The `justify-content` attribute will determine that.

```
.hero{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: left;
    margin-top: 6%;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%; 
}
```